# stay in the current window after hyperlink click

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-11

Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1
Default Browser: Internet Explorer Version 11

Need to open multiple hyperlinks in an Outlook mail.
How to open hyperlinks in a new tab in current (already open) window of Internet Explorer?

It is easier if the active window remains Outlook after the each hyperlink click than to switch back and forth from IE to Outlook after every hyperink click.

I do not want Internet Explorer to be the active window soon after I click the hyperlink. However the link should open in a new tab in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Does '**Ctrl+Left Mouse Button**' work???
Or else Use other keyboard shortcuts for IE

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/internet-explorer-keyboard-shortcuts#1TC=windows-7